# External webcam slow and lousy on a Mac mini?

Tags: macos, mojave, mac-mini, webcam

I run a 2012 Mac mini using a Logitech C920 HD Pro USB 1080p Webcam with it. Recently I've noticed it's *really* laggy. Even in a Skype test window or camera settings, it lags about a second and is very jerky.

Tests show I am getting about 1fps. I tried the Logi Capture app as suggested and it presented more settings but none helped.

Also: audio doesn't work on it. It reports as a microphone but didn't work as one.

Also: maybe a non-issue but my webcam device name is reported as "HD Pro Webcam C902 #2" - why #2? Some apps have a drop-down showing two cameras, this one and .

It seems to me like it's surely a driver issue but I cannot see Logitech provide drivers, and MacOS doesn't seem to recognize webcams as a category in Settings.

One thing I spotted while researching was about the Mic issue, it talked about changing the sound settings on the device:
[image]

But, on my Mac that *Format* drop-down is non-editable:
[image]

That might be a MacOS version discrepancy but I do feel for whatever reason, it is not properly supported at the hardware level.

Comment: How is the lighting? How does it work in photo booth? Run activity monitor and see if there are any obvious hold ups.  I have a fall 2014 mac mini.  I haven't noticed any performance issues with my Creative camera. I recall there is a paid app in the app store to make camera adjustments.  I have not used the app.

Comment: Google shows a lot of people having issues with this particular cam on Mac, but as many people saying it's great!

Comment: Are you using Logi Capture or some third party webcam app?

Comment: @Tetsujin no. I just plugged it in when I bought it and it (sort of) worked. When I did some earlier research I couldn't see any updated drivers or anything like that.

Comment: It may depend on how long you've had it. initially there was no app/driver/control panel at all for Mac, so you would be forced to use something like [Webcam Settings](https://apps.apple.com/gb/app/webcam-settings/id533696630?mt=12) in order to have any control over it. In recent times Logitech have actually got around to making a Mac App for it, Logi Capture, which I have downloaded but not yet tried, as I have the aforementioned Webcam Settings.

Comment: @Tetsujin a quick look suggests that's a whole suite of functionality. Webcam Settings sounds like probably the easiest solution, but it seems crazy I have to pay for a 3rd-party app to make Mac-compatible hardware work properly!

Answer (score 1):

So, I fixed it. By unplugging it, and plugging it back in to a different socket! Suddenly I get audio *and* the video is perfect.

It's not much of an answer but it was the solution for me!